# write list of list using latex

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I want to get something like this

[image]

I wrote this code

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        [[0 0 1 ... 0 -1 1]\\
        [0 0 -1 ... 0 1 1]\\
        [0 -1 0 ... 0 1 0]\\
        ...\\
        [0 1 0 ... 1 1 0]\\
        [1 0 0 ... -1 0 1]\\
        [-1 1 1 ... 1 0 0]]
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

but Im getting this

[image]

Comment: ``\\`` takes an optional argument, e.g. `\\[1cm]` to insert 1cm of vertical space, but when scanning for `[...]` whitespace (including linebreaks) is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BVerbatim` from `fancyvrb`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just to provide context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-6]
\[
\begin{BVerbatim}
[[0 0 1 ... 0 -1 1]
 [0 0 -1 ... 0 1 1]
 [0 -1 0 ... 0 1 0]
 ...
 [0 1 0 ... 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 ... -1 0 1]
 [-1 1 1 ... 1 0 0]]
\end{BVerbatim}
\]
\lipsum[1][1-6]

\end{document}
```

***Don't*** indent the contents of `BVerbatim`. You can use `center` instead of `\[...\]` (which, on the other hand, ensures no page breaks).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To display code, use the `verbatim` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
        \begin{verbatim}
        [[ 0  0  1 ...  0 -1  1]
         [ 0  0 -1 ...  0  1  1]
         [ 0 -1  0 ...  0  1  0]
         ...
         [ 0  1  0 ...  1  1  0]
         [ 1  0  0 ... -1  0  1]
         [-1  1  1 ...  1  0  0]]
        \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but I can't put that center in the document using \begin{center} \begin{verbatim} .... any idea how to do that ?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega I've updated the answer.  This needs a little bit of eyeballing the width.